# Ticket window or ticket counter 161

Tags: usage

Which one of the following two choices is correct?

> The **ticket window/ticket counter** remained closed throughout the day.

I think both are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use either and be understood, but if there's a piece of clear plastic between you and the person giving out tickets, that's a ticket window. Typically found on the exterior of the building or attraction. If you walk inside and talk to someone behind a desk to get tickets, that's a ticket counter. If they're in an isolated small building, you will hear that called a "ticket booth".